# How to make side bar upon button

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

[image]

How I can make side bar upon button to add the coin.

Comment: you can use [flutter_slidable](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_slidable)

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve that by using the `Dismissible` widget
here's a video on how to use it
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iEMgjrfuc58

Answer (score 0):

```
Use This Package:
```

**flutter_slidable: ^2.0.0**

```
Scaffold(
        body: ListView(
          children: [
            Slidable(
              // Specify a key if the Slidable is dismissible.
              key: const ValueKey(0),

              // The start action pane is the one at the left or the top side.
              startActionPane: ActionPane(
                // A motion is a widget used to control how the pane animates.
                motion: const ScrollMotion(),

                // A pane can dismiss the Slidable.
                dismissible: DismissiblePane(onDismissed: () {}),

                // All actions are defined in the children parameter.
                children: const [
                  // A SlidableAction can have an icon and/or a label.
                  SlidableAction(
                    onPressed: doNothing,
                    backgroundColor: Color(0xFFFE4A49),
                    foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                    icon: Icons.delete,
                    label: 'Delete',
                  ),
                  SlidableAction(
                    onPressed: doNothing,
                    backgroundColor: Color(0xFF21B7CA),
                    foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                    icon: Icons.share,
                    label: 'Share',
                  ),
                ],
              ),

              // The end action pane is the one at the right or the bottom side.
              endActionPane: const ActionPane(
                motion: ScrollMotion(),
                children: [
                  SlidableAction(
                    // An action can be bigger than the others.
                    flex: 2,
                    onPressed: doNothing,
                    backgroundColor: Color(0xFF7BC043),
                    foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                    icon: Icons.archive,
                    label: 'Archive',
                  ),
                  SlidableAction(
                    onPressed: doNothing,
                    backgroundColor: Color(0xFF0392CF),
                    foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                    icon: Icons.save,
                    label: 'Save',
                  ),
                ],
              ),

              // The child of the Slidable is what the user sees when the
              // component is not dragged.
              child: const ListTile(title: Text('Slide me')),
            ),
            Slidable(
              // Specify a key if the Slidable is dismissible.
              key: const ValueKey(1),

              // The start action pane is the one at the left or the top side.
              startActionPane: const ActionPane(
                // A motion is a widget used to control how the pane animates.
                motion: ScrollMotion(),

                // All actions are defined in the children parameter.
                children: [
                  // A SlidableAction can have an icon and/or a label.
                  SlidableAction(
                    onPressed: doNothing,
                    backgroundColor: Color(0xFFFE4A49),
                    foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                    icon: Icons.delete,
                    label: 'Delete',
                  ),
                  SlidableAction(
                    onPressed: doNothing,
                    backgroundColor: Color(0xFF21B7CA),
                    foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                    icon: Icons.share,
                    label: 'Share',
                  ),
                ],
              ),

              // The end action pane is the one at the right or the bottom side.
              endActionPane: ActionPane(
                motion: const ScrollMotion(),
                dismissible: DismissiblePane(onDismissed: () {}),
                children: const [
                  SlidableAction(
                    // An action can be bigger than the others.
                    flex: 2,
                    onPressed: doNothing,
                    backgroundColor: Color(0xFF7BC043),
                    foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                    icon: Icons.archive,
                    label: 'Archive',
                  ),
                  SlidableAction(
                    onPressed: doNothing,
                    backgroundColor: Color(0xFF0392CF),
                    foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                    icon: Icons.save,
                    label: 'Save',
                  ),
                ],
              ),

              // The child of the Slidable is what the user sees when the
              // component is not dragged.
              child: const ListTile(title: Text('Slide me')),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```